How to distinguish philosophical works from self-help books?
I imagine that the terms philosophical work and self-help book elicit different responses in most people, but there seems to be some overlap. For instance, the works of Epicurus are all about actively changing the way one leads one's life, and countless people have turned to the works of Marcus Aurelius or Francis Bacon to seek wisdom that may help them in their own lives. On the other hand, a book such as Women Who Love Too Much is certainly a self-help book (regardless of whether one agrees with advice given therein), but I don't think many would consider it to be a philosophical work.
My current thought is that self-help is an aspect of some (indeed many) philosophical works, but the distinguishing feature is that philosophical self-help derives from some kind of system or principle, say utilitarianism or Kant's categorical imperative, while a classic self-help book is isolated – save from perhaps results from psychology or (alas) sometimes pseudoscience – and focused solely on the individual achieving a certain goal.
This is hardly an important question, but I would be interested to hear other people's thoughts. For instance, is there a clear methodology, for distinguishing genuine philosophical works from mere self-help books?

Modern self-help is I suppose concerned with hypothetical-ends and practical advice on how to achieve them: how to get rich, how to find a partner, how to find happiness in the psychological sense. And philosophical debates about how to live are primarily concerned with the prior question about what we should be striving for; inquiry about categorical-ends, goals that are worthy as such not as means to something else. Happiness of course might be such a thing, but to inquire about true happiness (eudaimonia) and how to achieve it, is to ask such a question about ultimate ends.

I've added the implied question from your title because the forum, strictly speaking, disallows what-do-you-think questions, and this is a particularly good question. Feel free to roll back. Metaphilosophical questions  are particularly important IMNSHO.

If people esteem its pretige, it's prestigious. Looking for "genuineness" when what one really means is prestige is a pretty common error.

If we consider philosophy to be the endeavour to produce, critique and organize concepts, then the distinction becomes quite easy: does the book being considered introduce new concepts, or discuss and refine older ones, or try to show how they relate to other concepts and schools of thought?
Take a very famous and recognized self-help book, How to Win Friends and Influence People by Dale Carnegie. Although it contains very good advice it does not introduce new concepts or discuss older ones. It just presents an argument and vivid examples of how being likeable and respecting other people's motivations will help you find common ground and lead effectively.
On the other hand, although I haven't read it, it's my understanding that 12 Rules for Life by Jordan Peterson introduces and intends to refine the concepts of hierarchy, order and chaos, so, at least in part, it's a philosophy book.
Now, it does not mean that one is necessarily superior to the other. You can have bad philosophy just like you can have bad music or bad cinema. The Room by Tommy Wiseau is just as much a work of art as Citizen Kane, it's just that one is generally considered to be great and the other... not so much.
We have to mention here books that are philosophical but devoid of any ethical concern and not about self-help, such as Naming and Necessity by Saul Kripke, or neither philosophy nor self-help, such as A Tale of Two Cities.
In the end it seems philosophy and self-help are two unrelated domains, and as we have seen, a book can be about one, both or neither of them.

It's very difficult to discern. If we see philosophy as a way of life (= Ethics), the contents of Stoicism, Epicureanism, and certain forms of skepticism are practically indistinguishable from self-help books. Additionally, these Hellenistic currents derived from a presupposed interpretation of reality that they scarcely questioned.
If you refer to philosophy as the "science that is sought" (Aristotle), that is, as Theory, then what distinguishes it is a systematic and rational inquiry into reality taken in its own right -not to help us or be edifying, or to be useful for any other interest-, offering an object to philosophy (Being, Reality, Physis, Spirit, Matter, etc.) that gives formal unity to all its parts.

Regarding the classical schools of Stoicism, Epicureanism and so on: Hermotimus by Lucian backs up your point well.

@dwolfeu Thanks! I had forgotten about this work, but it came to mind that Tertullian mentioned it. I’ll dive into it!
